# How to get count of total push notifications in android for an application?

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, badge

I am working on badges on launcher icon of application in android,I want to get total number of push notification for my app to display as a badge on my app's launcher icon,I am using parse.com for the push notifications in android,So can any buddy please tell me how to get count of push notifications and reflect it in badge in android?

**code**

```
Parse.initialize(this, "Hl59kzuF4yGr36XEUZByOgtorvyrYcVm7zAb6amG",
            "YohxPugahDoiBZ2kaQ7qtqmO40y0JmLYkMuT");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, QuestionOFDayActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **parse.com** then you might have using `BroadcastReceiver` for handling push notification(if not then use that). 
So in `onRecieve()` of Broadcast receiver you can take `count` as application level. then u will get no. of push notification through out of app.

**Edited** :

Add this Receiver in your manifest

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.MyCustomReceiver" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="your.package.UPDATE_STATUS" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

create new class:-

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Here you will get the event when you receive Notification 
    // you can maintain a count here as application level. 
  }
}
```

If you want detailed doc - [Then read this](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving/Android)

Comment: Tarun than you so much for reply,can you please give me some code ,I have no idea of it.thank you

Comment: Are u creating notification bar by your self? or you left this on parse.com?

Comment: i just left it on parse.com

Comment: I have edited the post. If you have any prob, then ask me again

Comment: Tarun -Thank you bro,I have changed code as per yours,Now can  oyu tell how to get countsinside onReceive?Please

Comment: now start a counter - for every Notification ,onReceive() will call.